# Is this question about Firebase off-topic?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons, reopen-closed

Is this question off-topic: [How to send latitude and longitude of a Google Maps marker to Firebase - android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57607587/how-to-send-latitude-and-longitude-of-a-google-maps-marker-to-firebase-android)

It's a question about how to store latitude and longitude values in Firebase, perfectly good with the guidelines. I tried to find the reason why it might be closed, but I couldn't.

Could somebody explain why it is off-topic or not?

Comment: The specific close-reason given is that it lacks the necessary details to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @yivi Yeah, what does it lack? That's what I can't understand. Because it has the code, a good question and, in my opinion, everything needed.

Comment: I don't know. I'm just telling you what the close reason says.

Comment: "It has code", yes it has, but it is still basically "write code for me" request. There is zero effort in trying to actually use Firebase.

Comment: Yes, it contains code that *isn't* particularly relevant, but no *relevant* code, and no indication of what happened with whatever the OP attempted.

Comment: "I want" isn't a question, it's a request/demand. All the OP does in the post is tells us that they "want" something, then pastas some code into the "question". They don't tell us what's wrong with said code, why it doesn't work, etc, etc.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar Thanks to everybody here! I thought the code was relevant but still, I might have been a bit biased as I answered the question, thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not knowing anything about the technologies, I read:

> I want to do X.  I have already done Y.  And I want to do Z.
>
> *code goes here*

Not a lot of actual question in this, so there's not a lot of answering that can be done.  We don't *know* what the issue actually is, so how could we realistically answer it for the OP if all they're doing is expressing their earnest wishes for their application?